# Getting rid of type conflicts running tsc in angular application with @types/react dependencies

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, tsconfig

I'm currently working on an angular application which needs to be build with `tsc` for code quality checking framework. Building the application with `ng build` works just fine, but when trying to build the application with pure `tsc`, we are facing multiple type conflicting errors like this:

```
node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3444:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'view' must be of type 'SVGProps<SVGViewElement>', but here has type 'SVGProps<SVGViewElement>'.
```

The react typings coming from two dependencies we are using: `@apollo/client` (prod dep) and `@storybook/angular` (dev dep).

Is there any way to solve this issue? Or should I get in touch with the support of the code quality framework?